# PHP Curl to hastebin.com API doesn't work

Tags: php, api, curl

I'd like to submit a new paste to hastebin.com using it's API, which I stumbled upon at: https://github.com/seejohnrun/haste-server/wiki/POST-api

I've tried several ways but couldn't make it to work. Here's my simple code:

```
    if(function_exists('curl_init')) {
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "http://hastebin.com/documents" );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     'hello world'); 
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'data=hello world');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('data'=>'hello world'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/plain'));

        $response_json = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response_array = json_decode($response_json,true);
        print_r ($response_array);

    } else {
        error_log("You need cURL to use this api!");
    }
```

Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Hastebin looks like are redirecting their http scheme to https. So you'll need to use `https://hastebin.com/documents`.

All the rest seems to be the same as before.